# live agent querying existing case fields

Tags: liveagent

After agent accepts the chat for existing case, querying existing case from customized prechat form, can i check whether first response (SLA) of the case is completed or not ? if yes, how can i check ? by using which objects i can check.

Now the prechat is customized by using below visual force page code :

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Case" value="CaseNumber,true;" />
 <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Case" value="CaseNumber,true;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.query:CaseNumber" value="Case,CaseNumber" />
```

I tried to pass the case number in my controller to check case milestone is compeleted.  but i am not able to acheive this.

```
<!--input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.save:CaseNumber" value= "{!CN}" />


public class LiveAgentPreChatController {


public Id CN{get;set;}

public LiveAgentPreChatController() {

        getCaseMileStoneSLASLO();
    }


    public void getCaseMileStoneSLASLO() {
         system.debug('%%%%%case number'+CN);  
           return;
           Case c = [SELECT  id,
                     (SELECT CaseId, TargetDate, IsCompleted, IsViolated
                      FROM CaseMilestones
                      WHERE IsCompleted = false)
                      FROM Case
                      WHERE CaseNumber =:CN LIMIT 1];



        if(c.id != null){
            CaseComment cm = new CaseComment();
            cm.ParentId= c.id;
            cm.CommentBody  = ' test 123';
            cm.IsPublished  = true;
            insert cm;
        }
        update c;
    }

}
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Case" value="CaseNumber,true;" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Case" value="CaseNumber,true;" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.query:CaseNumber" value="Case,CaseNumber" />

Comment: Use the code formatting button to format code. Highlight the lines, then click the `{}` icon, and itll indent it four spaces for you, showing it all as code blocks.